# How can I reference a table in dbt using its alias and a var, not its resource name?

Tags: dbt

I have been able to create a reasonably complex dbt model which contains several models all of which rely on a single model that acts as a filter.

Broadly, the numerous models follow the pattern:

```
{{ config(materialized = 'view') }}

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TABLE
INNER JOIN 
    {{ ref('filter_table') }} FILTER 
ON 
    TABLE.KEY = FILTER.KEY
```

The filter table, let's imagine it's called *filter_table.sql* is simply:

```
{{ config(materialized = 'view') }}

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    FILTER_SOURCE
WHERE 
    RELEVANT = True
```

This works fine when I reference it in the numerous models like this: `{{ ref('filter_table') }}`.

However, when I try to use an alias in the filter table it seems that the alias is not resolved in time for dbt to be able to recognise it.

I amend the config of *filter_table.sql* to this...

```
{{ config(materialized = 'view', alias = 'FILT') }}
```

...and the references in the dependant models like this...

```
{{ ref(var('filter_table_alias')) }}
```

...with a var in *dbt_project.yml* set like this:

```
vars: 
  filter_table_alias: 'FILT'
```

I get a message though which states that the node named 'FILT' is not found.

So my working theory is that although dbt recognised the dependencies based on how the refs are set up it is not able to do this using an alias - presumably the alias is not processed by the time that it is setting up the graph.

Is there a quick way to set up the alias and force it to be loaded first?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: `alias` does sound like it should create a name that you can refer to. It's a confusing label for what it actually does: allow you to override the normal behavior of using the file/model and instead use the alias to name of the table/view (relation) in the destination database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alias` only impacts the name of the relation where the model is materialized in your database. `ref` always takes a model name, not an alias.

So you can add an `alias = 'FILT'` config to your filter table if you want, but in the other models you must continue to `ref('filter_table')`.

The reason for this distinction is that dbt model names must be unique (within a dbt package/project), but aliases need not be unique (if they are materialized to different schemas).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to take advantage of dbt Classing - check out `api.Relation`, in which the `identifier` could be set as the `alias` I believe...

Comment: This is more of a a helpful comment than an answer. Looking at the dbt Relation class, the identifier is the name of the view or table - see https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes The alias can be used to change the identifier, not the other way around.